# How to blend a political map with a terrain?

Tags: unity-game-engine, terrain

How do some strategy games have a terrain that blends with a changeable map?
I mean what is the technique that developers use?

For example,

[image]

Comment: Can you explain your question better? not sure about what are you looking for

Comment: Yes of course! i'm looking for the recommended way to make the terrain like this without turning it into a mesh and assigning the texture on it, I only looking for an explanation is it a coding thing? or shaders..etc

Comment: but your terrain is a terrain? you change land randomly in runtime? only need to match the texture? what are you trying to do with this zones?

Comment: Ok there is no problem to convert my terrain into a mesh because i don't want to edit it in runtime, the main question is about what is the way to make the changeable political map to match the terrain mesh

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that they actually splice the terrain into different meshes for each of the provinces and then assign a different material and texture to it when it changes hands.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a good way to make this work

Unity has a feature or component called (Projector) you can use it to make your texture blend with anything meshes, terrains, and you can place a shader to the projector if you want to change the territory color in runtime! I think this is one of the tricks that strategy game developers used